# Ошибка преобразования текста в число

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Пишу в *Visual Studio 2015* программу с помощью *WindowsForms*.
Имеются 4 шт `textBox`, в которых нужно вводить цифровые значения и 
`label10`, куда отображается результат вычислений после нажатия кнопки `button1`. 
Вот фрагмент кода:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label10.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(textBox1) * 
                                    Convert.ToDouble(textBox2) * 
                                    Convert.ToDouble(textBox3) * 
                                    Convert.ToDouble(textBox4) * 0.00000786);
}
```

Запускаю, ввожу 4 значения, нажимаю на кнопку и выскакивает ошибка:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

При этом редактор подсвечивает почему-то точку с запятой в конце строки. Менял конвертирование и на `Float`, и на разные `Int16`, `Int32` - результата нет.

Помогите исправить ошибку.

Comment: `textBox1.Text` и так далее

Comment: Вот спасибо, какой же я невнимательный.

Comment: Можете использовать `NumericUpDown` вместо `TextBox`. Он позволяет вводить только числа (как целые, так и вещественные).